# Change in the bayesian network structure

Tags: probability, bayesian, bayesian-networks, probability-theory

I'm learning a bayesian network and was wondering if it is possible to merge multiple children into a single child? For example in the figure below, could it be possible to have a single conditional probability table (Node **DEF**) from the three conditional probability tables (**D, E, F**).
[image]

If it's not possible, is there any work to make independent events to dependent event?

Thank you all

Answer (score 1):

This question is not very well asked, so it is difficult to answer.

First of all the nodes of a BN are not events but random variables.

Secondly, merging nodes requires a justification of this merge. The first idea would be to generate a multidimensional variable with 8 values, which represents exactly the 8 possible values of DEF.

[image: attemp1]

It is also possible to set up merging solutions like aggregators: an AND, an OR, a noisyOR, etc...

[image: attempt2]

Finally, there is a large literature on sensor data fusion that certainly deserves to be looked at closely.